# jQuery Mobile page scoped element identification

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have two pages in my jQuery Mobile app. Both elements are lists that show a list of places returned from a server. In a normal web-app I would do "id='places'" on both of them, but in a  multi-page jQuery Mobile app ids should be unique. What are the good alternatives to using ids to work around this id uniqueness restriction?

I could include page name in the id, for example: **`id='searchPage-places'`** and `id='favPage-places'` but it adds unnecessary noise, since I always access places element from a page-specific javascript content.

I think using `data-role` would be correct and appropriate, but I do not want to interfere with jQM's own data-role semantic.

**`data-id`** feels like a hack

using **classes** feels like a hack too.

I am looking for an elegant technique for a page-scoped element identification in a jQuery Mobile app.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create your own attribute data-custom (or any other appropriate name)? It can be easily accessed with jQuery.

Or you can still use same id for both of them and access it through a pageID + 'places',  for example:

```
$('#page1[data-role="page"] #places')
```

for the first page and

```
$('#page2[data-role="page"] #places')
```

for the other one.

Comment: I did say that data-role would be ideal but I said I don't want to interfere with jqms own data-role semantic.

Comment: I don't mind using my own data-* attribute, but I can't think of a good noun to describe the semantic.

Comment: Then pick any you think appropriate.